# Calculating Days, Hours, Minutes, Seconds Between Two Dates. Easier Way?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get the years, days, hours, and seconds between two different dates. I'm having trouble getting the date variables stored properly so they can interact and be subtracted from each other. Is there an easier way to do what I'm trying to do? (can't use outside libs)

```
function daylightTime()
{
  var userYearCurrent = prompt("Enter a year in numbers(2019)","Enter a year ex: 2019, 2020, 2021");
  var userMonthCurrent = prompt("Enter a month in numbers(1-12), or type a month name","Enter a month ex: 11, November");
  var userDayCurrent = prompt("Enter a day of The month in mumbers(1-31)","Enter a day of the month ex: 14, 21");
  var userTimeCurrent = prompt("Enter a time (2:05) or if seconds are needed(2:05:30)","Enter a time of day ex: 11:15, do not use military time");
  var amOrPMCurrent = prompt("Enter either AM or PM","Enter either AM or PM ex: AM");

  var userYearCurrent = prompt("Enter a FUTURE year in numbers(2019)","Enter a year ex: 2019, 2020, 2021");
  var userMonthFuture = prompt("Enter a FUTURE month in numbers(1-12), or type a month name","Enter a month ex: 11, November");
  var userDayFuture = prompt("Enter a FUTURE day of The month in mumbers(1-31)","Enter a day of the month ex: 14, 21");
  var userTimeFuture = prompt("Enter a FUTURE time (2:05) or if seconds are needed(2:05:30)","Enter a time of day ex: 11:15, do not use military time");
  var amOrPMFuture = prompt("Enter either AM or PM","Enter either AM or PM ex: AM");

  var dateCurrent = new Date(userMonthCurrent+" "+userDayCurrent+", "+userYearCurrent+" "+userTimeCurrent+" "+amOrPMCurrent);
  var dateFuture = new Date(userMonthFuture+" "+userDayFuture+", "+userYearFuture+" "+userTimeFuture+" "+amOrPMFuture);

  var mathSeconds = Math.abs(dateFuture.getTime()  - dateCurrent.getTime()) / 1000;
  var days = Math.floor(mathSeconds / 86400);
  mathSeconds -= days * 86400;
  var hours = Math.floor(mathSeconds / 3600) % 24;
  mathSeconds -= hours * 3600;
  var minutes = Math.floor(mathSeconds / 60) % 60;
  mathSeconds -= minutes * 60;
  var seconds = mathSeconds;

  document.getElementById("time2").innerHTML = "Time between your two dates: " + days + " Days: " + hours + " Hours: " + minutes + " Minutes: " + seconds + " Seconds";
}
```

Comment: Can you clarify what exactly you're having trouble with? Is it not working how you expect, and if so, what exactly is wrong? Are you just looking for a simpler solution? Something else?

Comment: I just noticed you wrote `userYearCurrent` twice, presumably the second one should be `userYearFuture`. Was that a mistake copying it here, or if it's in your actual code does that fix it?

Comment: @JohnMontgomery I think I am having trouble with this line:

```var dateCurrent = new Date(userMonthCurrent, userDayCurrent, userYearCurrent, userTimeCurrent, amOrPMCurrent);
var dateFuture = new Date(userMonthFuture, userDayFuture, userYearFuture, userTimeFuture, amOrPMFuture);```

It returns NaN NaN NaN etc, so having trouble subtracting the dates from each other. I removed the + and tried commas, no difference.